# Syntax highlighting PHP variable in Codemirror 6 editor

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

Is there any option to highlight PHP variables in Codemirror version 6 editor. This was possible in version 5, but currently it looks like there is no such option in version 6.

[image]